# Plotting two variables with a different scale on the same chart

Tags: r, plot

I'm using RStudio. I have a dataframe called *data*.

I've plotted these variables separately:

```
data_tmp<-xts(as.matrix(data[,-1]), order.by = data$date)

autoplot(data_tmp$sales)

autoplot(data_tmp$temperature)
```

I would like to combine the variables "sales" and "temperature" in a single graph, with a different colour for each variable, so I can check the seasonality and if they are correlated.
The problem that I'm facing is the differences in the scale. I would like to create two 'y' axis so both variables are with the same scale.

Comment: Creating two y-axis in ggplot2 was (in the past) considered a bit of a workaround. This post might give you what you need though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales